# Javascript Ajax Callback function not defined error

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I tried searching all around since this seems to me a very common (NuBee?) problem, but nothing worked for me...so here it is

To cut right to the chase, my Razor code (shown later) posts an ajax form to a MVC4 action which works fine but any attempt to add a callback function to the form (`OnSuccess`, `OnBegin` etc) fails with a runtime error that the callback function is not defined. This is the image of the error message in the my Chrome browser, right after the exception occurs:

[image: JSChromeError]

This is the form's code:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AskQuestion", null, 
        new AjaxOptions() { 
            OnSuccess = "endAskQuestion" },
        new { id = "askQuestionForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>@ViewBag.Controller</legend>
            <br />
            @{ var investigationID = Model.Investigation.InvestigationID; }
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => investigationID)
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="שלח היגד"/>
            <input type="button" id="cancelEdit" class="button" value="בטל עריכה"/>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

And the script inside which the `endAskQuestion` is defined:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //deleted several Jquery and JS functions...

    // callback function definition
    function endAskQuestion() {
        alert("adad");
    }
})
```

Also, I saw some posts that stated the references to JQuery and Ajax scripts are important so here's the html's head section with the references:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>RTInvestigation</title>
    <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="/Content/css?v=_WuF_JGHabtqdWNcwICWILVG9A391eZyF0GO24jlq9U1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script> </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

</head>
```

I don't know why Razor creates references for two Jquery-UI versions...I couldn't find the reason.

How come the callback function is not defined??

Thanks for helping

Comment: You're code is producing some form of IIFE and it doesn't define your function `endAskQuestion`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `endAskQuestion` out of the `$(document).ready` function.  Also, use a semicolon at the end of each javascript code line, as that will often throw undefined errors, as well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //deleted several Jquery and JS functions...

}); // added semicolon here...

// callback function definition should be moved outside
function endAskQuestion() {
    alert("adad");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your `endAskQuestion` is limited to the anonymous function that jQuery calls when the document is ready. As ps2goat says, you need to take it out of the $(document).ready callback. In this way it will be defined globally and will be accesible through closure to the callbakc you're using for AJAX. Read about scoping, closures and anonymou.

Comment: Had a feeling the function's scope was the issue, should really read about scoping in JS scripts. Tnx